# Como traducir campos en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo algunas tablas y campos en inglés en mi base de datos (y estos deben de estar así). Pero por otro lado, cuando hago una select, el nombre de los campos tienen que salir en español.
Ejemplo:
- Nombre del campo en la BBDD: employeeName
- Nombre que debe salir en mi select: Nombre
Seria algo así como un select employeeName as Nombre.

El problema es que son muchas tablas y muchos campos por tabla... Y si cada select que hago tengo que poner los alias a todos los campos...lo veo poco práctico.

Hay alguna manera de traducir los campos de manera automática? Como un alias automático?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías crear una vista por cada tabla y colocarle un alias a cada uno de los campos:

```
CREATE VIEW empleados AS
SELECT employeeName AS Nombre FROM employees;
```

La consulta te quedaría:

```
SELECT Nombre FROM empleados;
```

Comment: Me parece una buena idea. Solo un comentario, las selects que tengo, normalment tienen JOINS, y no se hasta que punto hacer las JOINS entre vistas puede ser algo costoso.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una tabla de alias para coger el alias de esa tabla y no tener que escribirlo cada vez.

Tabla esp
Name   Nombre
...

Y haces la `query` asignando el alias

```
select Name as esp.Name from mitabla
```

**Edición para ampliar la respuesta**

Otra forma si estás usando por ejemplo PHP para hacer la consulta (no sé si es el caso) es tener los campos con su alias en array para llamarlos desde una variable, pero desde el punto de vista de la secuencia MySQL la idea es la misma:

`$a["name"] = "Name as Nombre";` o `$a["name"] = "Name as esp.Name";`

```
select $a["name"] from mitabla;
```

En cualquier caso implica que hagas en algún momento la traducción.

Comment: Esa es la forma que habia pensado... pero no sabia exactamente como ejecutarlo. Pero igualmente a cada select que haga, tengo que asignar un alias para cada campo. Imagínate que tengo que hacer 30 querys con 50 campos en cada query... Gracias por la aportación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. La verdad es que estoy utilizando Java para mostrar los datos en las tablas.
La idea de utilizar vistas como decían por arriba no me desagrada.

Comment: Hola, una pregunta... la relación entre la tabla de "alias" y la tabla madre... ¿Cómo la harías para poder asignar el alias al campo correspondiente?
Gracias :)

Comment: A cada campo le pongo el nombre que tiene en inglés (Name) y lo relleno con el traducido (Nombre), de manera que si la tabla se llama 'esp' el valor de esp.Name es Nombre. Así no tienes que pensar el nombre del alias, es igual que el de tu campo pero referido a la tabla con la traducción.